# MacOS swiftUI copy the text from the clipboard into a TextField field

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swiftui, paste

I have to make sure that when the input field appears, to take the text that is on the clipboard and insert it as the text of the input field if it meets specific conditions.

For this I am using `onAppear` on the input field, the problem is how to get the text.

Can anyone help me out?

```swift
                    TextField("Git Repository URL", text: $repoUrlStr)
                        .lineLimit(1)
                        .padding(.bottom, 15)
                        .frame(width: 300)
                        .onAppear {
                            // Write to pasteboard
                            let pasteboard = NSPasteboard.general
                            pasteboard.declareTypes([NSPasteboard.PasteboardType.string], owner: nil)
                            //pasteboard.setString("Good Morning", forType: NSPasteboard.PasteboardType.string)

                            // Read from pasteboard
                            let read = pasteboard.pasteboardItems?.first?.string(forType: .string)
                            print("ok", read)
                        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this approach, to show what you read from the `Pasteboard` into the `TextField` text: (use `cmd+c` to copy some text into the pasteboard before you run the app)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var repoUrlStr = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Git Repository URL", text: $repoUrlStr)
            .lineLimit(1)
            .padding(.bottom, 15)
            .frame(width: 300)
            .onAppear {
                if let read = NSPasteboard.general.string(forType: .string) {
                    repoUrlStr = read  // <-- here
                }
            }.frame(width: 444, height: 444)
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the writing I want to copy is not "Good Morning" but what is in my notes(cmd+v).

Comment: use the "alternatively" code, with (cmd+c). I'll update my answer.